# python unpacking a list directly with *var into strings and not list

Tags: python, list

Is there a way to get the var a directly as a space separated string and not a list?

```
>>> *a,b,c=["one","two","three","four","five"]    
>>> a,b,c
(['one', 'two', 'three'], 'four', 'five')
>>> " ".join(a),b,c
('one two three', 'four', 'five')

*(" ".join(a)),b,c= ["one","two","three","four","five"]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call

>>> " ".join(*a),b,c= ["one","two","three","four","five"]    
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
```

Comment: what result did you expect?

Comment: @ncopiy I wash a lot of csv files where ordering is different from file to file.It is the a I input directly into a parser, so a one liner to get `a="one two three"`. I've washed 100eds of files and they all boil down to split of N columns and collect the rest into a space separated string

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a little helper function?

```
def parse_list(mylist):
    *a,b,c = mylist
    return " ".join(a),b,c

a,b,c = parse_list(["one","two","three","four","five"])
a,b,c
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, but you have to bend over backwards for it. You can't do the joining on the left hand side, you have to produce this value on the right hand side:

```
('one two three', 'four', 'five')
```

You can do so like this:

```
l = ["one","two","three","four","five"]
a, b, c = [' '.join(l[:-2])] + l[-2:]
```

Not exactly what I'd call intuitive, joining `a` after the fact seems way easier…

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list with the unpacked variables and then join its elements:

```
*a,b,c=["one","two","three","four","five"]
output = " ".join([*a,b,c])
print(output)
```

Output:

```
one two three four five
```

Comment: I need the `a = "one two three"`